# Release viewcontroller in the stack (after didReceiveMemoryWarning)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, release, didreceivememorywarning

I want to remove all viewcontrollers (except Root) in the stack to release memory after "memory warning".

I popToRootViewController in the last controller.

Process: *Root (push)-> AController (push)-> BController (after memory warning go back)-> Root*

(in BController)

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    CMLog(@"BController");

    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    CMLog(@"[allControllers lastObject]");
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Logs

1. Received memory warning.
2. [RootViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning]
3. [AController didReceiveMemoryWarning]
4. [BController didReceiveMemoryWarning]
5. [BController didReceiveMemoryWarning]:[allControllers lastObject]
6. (popToRootViewControllerAnimated)

so i repeat the process

1. Received memory warning.
2. [RootViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning]
3. [AController didReceiveMemoryWarning]
4. [BController didReceiveMemoryWarning]
5. [AController didReceiveMemoryWarning](<<<< **duplicate**)
6. [BController didReceiveMemoryWarning](<<<< **duplicate**)
7. [BController didReceiveMemoryWarning]:[allControllers lastObject]
8. (popToRootViewControllerAnimated)

After several tries the app crash because low memory

Can i simply remove the view controller in the [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10281607/900763)? and will release memory?

Comment: What if the user is using your app while this happens? That's not a very good user experience.

Comment: `navigationController` property will be the same for each of the stack controllers, that said it would be much easier to call `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` only from the root `VC`. It will be critical to make sure your child `VC` are not over retained as in this case they will be able to receive notifications and have correct reference to `navigationController`.

Comment: i have @property (nonatomic, retain) and also IBOutlet, i release in dealloc and didReceiveMemoryWarning (release and nil) and still continue call the viewcontroller but is not in the stack.