# Push action for UIPopOverController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a pop over to view my settings like this,

```
if ([popoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [popoverController
     dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
} else {

    UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc]
                           initWithFrame:CGRectMake(566, 440, 0, 0)];

    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    controller1.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(300, 115);

    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                         initWithContentViewController:controller1];


    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:popoverView.frame
                                       inView:self.view
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                     animated:YES];
}
```

my push action code:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard
                            storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                            bundle:nil];

UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)[storyboard
                                                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PCBViewController"];

[self.navigationController
 pushViewController:controller
 animated:YES];
```

In my settings popover has some buttons.  Those button is clicked, view controller open through push action but its not working.

My Question is: How to set push action for popover contents.

Comment: Show your code for push actions

Comment: You need to implement the **push** (ViewController) via UINavigationController...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view is presented from popover thus self.navigationController will be nil.

Try this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard
                            storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                            bundle:nil];

UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)[storyboard
                                                    instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PCBViewController"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[navigationController
 pushViewController:controller
 animated:YES];
```

Comment: i tried but i got these error  2013-11-19 10:20:22.604 CoinsAndBills_aus[1699:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing the same view controller instance more than once is not supported (<StageViewController: 0xb3e5600>)'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: I guess the view you are pushing already exists in navigation stack. You should pop view from navigation stack if it is no longer used.

Comment: look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281545/removing-viewcontrollers-from-navigation-stack

Answer (score 0):

you need to set up navigation controller for the view controller to allow navigation.

in your .h file

```
UINavigationController *navevent;
UIViewController *yourViewController
```

in .m file synthasize it and in view did load

```
 navevent=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:yourViewController];
 yourViewController=[[UIViewController alloc]init];
```

then create your popover like this

```
yourViewController.view = yourView;
 self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:navevent] ;
```

hope this help