# iOS Controlling Back Button from Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

I have a three views: 
1) the initial on my Tab Bar 
2) view segued from #1
3) view segued from #2

The normal use of the App is to start at #1, go to #2, then #3, which will always go back to #2.  I would like the back button for #2 to ALWAYS go back to #1.  However, after #3 has be entered and returned to #2, the back button goes to #3 (instead I want #1).  I currently use push segues.  Any ideas on how to update this?

Comment: How are you returning to 2? You should be popping 3 off of the stack. It sounds like you are pushing a new 2 on to the stack

Comment: @Paul.s returning to 2 with a segue from 3.  So yes, you are correct, I'm pushing a new 2 onto the stack.  How do I pop 3 off stack?

Comment: If it were me I would probably make 3 call back to 2 to say "I'm finished" at which point 2 would decide how to dismiss 3 as it knows how it was presented (navigationController/Modal/other). In this case 2 would just call `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

Comment: @Paul.s the popViewControllerAnimated:YES just segues back to 1 from 2.  When I put it in 3, the program crashes

Comment: How/where have you implemented this?

Comment: It shouldn't crash if you put it in 3 (which is where it should be if you're going from 3 to 2). Make sure you don't have any "backwards" segues (going from 3 to 2 or 2 to 1) still in your project. Are you getting an error message when it crashes? If so, post it.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
popToRootViewControllerAnimated:
```

instead of:

```
popViewControllerAnimated:
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving using this link [Removing viewcontrollers from navigation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281545/removing-viewcontrollers-from-navigation-stack) and surrounding it with an if statement to detect at least 2 view controllers:

```
 - (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
int i = [navigationArray count];

// [navigationArray removeAllObjects];    // This is just for remove all view controller from navigation stack.
if (i > 1){
    NSLog(@"count: %d", i);
    [navigationArray removeObjectAtIndex: 1];  // You can pass your index here
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationArray;
}
}
```