# iOS not sure how to solve navigation design in my app

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

My app inits with a navigation controller that opens up a table view.

If I then click on the menu icon in the header a modal segue gets fired and a login screen shows up. If you then login another modal segue gets fired and you end up on the account screen.

What I now want to do is to remove all other underlying VC's and make the account VC the first VC in the navigation stack. Is that possible?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281545/removing-viewcontrollers-from-navigation-stack

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible with `setViewControllers:animated:`, you can even make the transition animatable:

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[navigationController setViewControllers:@[viewController] animated:YES];
```

Comment: You asked if you can make your account VC first in the stack. `ViewController` in my example is your account VC.

Comment: Yes but where?
import UIKit

class AccountViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let viewController: UIViewController = AccountViewController()
        navigationController!.setViewControllers([viewController], animated: true)
    }

}
Says found nil.
Can you provide a full example?

Comment: provide your full code in your edit, not in comment - it's unreadable