# iOS: remove view controller from navigation stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigation based app that requires a passcode to view some pages. When I am on **Controller A** I want to push to the **Passcode Controller** then push to **Controller B** and remove the **Passcode Controller** from the stack.

So to be clear, **Passcode Controller** is stuck in between **Controller A** and **Controller B** and I do not know how to remove it.

I've tried two different approaches but neither is giving me the right result.

**Attempt 1:**

```
ControllerB *contB = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contB"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:contB animated:YES];

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
ControllerB *contB = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contB"];

ControllerA *contA = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"contA"];

[UIView transitionFromView:contA.view
                  toView:contB.view
                  duration:0.65f
                  options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut | UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve)
                  completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        self.view.window.rootViewController = contA;
                    }];
```

Does anyone know how I can remove **Passcode Controller** from the stack whenever I push **Controller B** from the **Passcode Controller**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `viewControllers` property on `UINavigationController`, like so:

```
self.navigationController.viewControllers = @[ contA, contB ];
```

Typically, you want to execute this line after control has passed to controller B.

This question has some other code samples: [Removing viewcontrollers from navigation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281545/removing-viewcontrollers-from-navigation-stack)

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer from the link you provided that I used: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10281607/3543861