# How to Remove a Parent View Controller in Swift

Tags: swift

There are A,B and C-View Controller.From A view controller, I used navigation push syntax to move to B.From B View Controller I used the same syntax to move to C.So that B becomes parent of C.Now I have to remove B View Controller from the stack.Can anyone suggest how to remove Parent View.When I press back button the page should redirect to A view controller From C view controller.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281545/removing-viewcontrollers-from-navigation-stack

Answer (score 0):

Use the `popToViewController:animated:` method provided by `UINavigationController` ([details here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:))

You can get a reference to AViewController using the `viewControllers` [property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers) that `UINavigationController` provides

If your AViewController is the root vc of the nav controller, you can use the `popToRootViewController:animated:` method

Comment: No, I just want to remove reference in place to that view controller I want to assign another view controller

Comment: Replace `BViewController` in `viewControllers` with `AnotherViewController`. But for the case you described (go back from C to A), pop would be more appropriate

Comment: When I used pop its not getting pop.Because the reference  of B get deleted .I have to replace some other rederence

Comment: Why are you deleting the reference of B? If you don't want to display it, use the popToViewController: method instead of deleting references. Ideally the viewcontroller stack should be left alone!

Comment: Actually, I want to include reference A in place of B.If I used pop its simple getting pop .It's not going to the view what I need