# How to remove all viewControllers except one from stack in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have 4 view controllers suppose A,B,C,D. ViewController D is on top and on click of button I have to go to ViewController A and remove all remaining ViewControllers. How to achieve this

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller or added a child controller?

Comment: Please provide more information... what is this "stack"?

Comment: If I understood correctly, something like [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; should work!

Comment: For swift 5, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/57327328/10579134

Answer (score 3):

```
self.navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

The `UINavigationController`'s viewControllers property is `get set` property, that means you could write your own array of view controllers.

example,

```
let VCs = self.navigationController.viewControllers    //VCs = [A, B, C, D]

let vcA  = VCs[0]    //vcA = A
//finally
self.navigationController.viewControllers = [vcA] //done
// OR
self.navigationController.setViewControllers([vcA], animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for one viewController in the stack. I have also added the code for if you couldn't find that one controller in the stack goto mainController or the firstController in the stack:

```
if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
    var element_count = 0
    for controller in viewControllers {
        if controller is YourViewController {
            element_count = 1
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
            break
        }
    }
    if element_count != 1{
        _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?