# How can I remove Previous View Controller from navigation controller ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to remove Previous view controller from navigation stack.

For example

-> A is root view.now navigate to B - b navigate to c - c navigate to c - c navigate to c

-->  now i want to remove all c view controller & pop to B

B is not Fix view controller.

## Another example

A - > b -> c > g  > c > f > c > c  > c > c

Remove all c View controller from navigation & need following output

A - > b -> c > g  > c > f

Please help me

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10281744/4763963

Comment: I already check this.but not working

Comment: What I'm not able to understand is that, how can you navigate from c to c.
> A - > b -> c > g > c > f > c > c > c > c

Answer (score 2):

Identify the controller from navigation stack. And pop to that controller

```
  NSArray *viewControllers = [[self navigationController] viewControllers];
  int count = [viewControllers count];

  for (int i= count-2; i >= 0 ; i--) {

        id obj=[viewControllers objectAtIndex:i];

        if(![obj isKindOfClass:[C class]]){
           [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
            return;
        }
   }
```

Comment: it will go to first non matching viewcontroller by passing all view controllers above in navigation stack

Comment: Yes, that what he wants.. check his example @suhit

Comment: navigation stack is 'A - > b -> c > g > c > f > c > c > c > c'  output required is 'A - > b -> c > g > c > f' your solution will show ViewController-A as it will stop at first index itself.

Comment: @suhit Thanks for info.. I am just updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `popToViewController` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621871-poptoviewcontroller).

example:

In Objective C

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:self.navigationController.viewControllers[your_VC_index] animated: true]; 
// in first eg your_VC_index will be 1 and another example it will be 5
```

In Swift 3

```
self.navigationController.popToViewController( self.navigationController.viewControllers[your_VC_index], animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

reverse iterate over navigation stack and get the index of first non matching viewController and then popToViewController

```
if let controllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
   var count = controllers.count - 1
   for viewcontroller in controllers.reversed() {
       if viewcontroller is CViewController {
          count -= 1
       } else {
          break
       }
    }

    let vc = controllers[count]
    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a method something like the following,

```
- (void)removeAllLastCObjectsFromNavigationController {
    //fetch viewcontroller array. for your case which will be A - > b -> c > g > c > f > c > c > c > c
    NSArray *viewControllers = yourNavigationController.viewControllers;
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: viewControllers];

    while(1) {
        id viewController = mutableArray.lastObject;
        if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[YourCClassName class]]) {
            //Now continue removing the objects from the array if that is C type object.
            [mutableArray removeLastObject];
        } else {
            //If found any other class than C stop removing viewcontroller
            break;
        }
    }
    //Now mutableArray contains A - > b -> c > g > c > f
    yourNavigationController.viewControllers = mutableArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the childViewControllers of navigationController is a stack,
So use this function, you can pop to f viewController and the " c > c > c > c" was destroyed.

```
for (UIViewController *tempVC in self.navigationController.childViewControllers) {
    if ([tempVC isKindOfClass:[fViewController class]]) {
        fViewController *f = (fViewController *)tempVC;
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:f animated:YES];
    }
}
```

However, if you don't want to pop to f, just want to get the new childViewControllers of navigationController. you can use next functions:

```
for (UIViewController *tempVC in self.navigationController.childViewControllers) {
    if ([tempVC isKindOfClass:[ScanViewController class]]) {
        NSUInteger findex = [self.navigationController.childViewControllers indexOfObject:tempVC];
        NSMutableArray *viewArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.childViewControllers];
        [viewArray removeObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(findex, viewArray.count - 1)];
    }
}
```

The viewArray is the new childViewControllers.And if you have new demand, can edit this function then use it.