# Remove all ViewControllers except current from navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

I am writing an IOS app in Swift.

After navigating to VC, I need to remove all **view controllers** except current (onscreen) from **navigation controller**. I am using below code and its working fine. But, it doesn't look optimized solution. Any better solution like syntactic sugar like map, filter, etc:

```
 if let nc = appDelegate().baseNavigationController{
   nc.viewControllers = Array(nc.viewControllers.dropLast(nc.viewControllers.count-1)
 }
```

Comment: try `nc.viewControllers = [nc.viewControllers.last!]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing viewcontrollers from navigation stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281545/removing-viewcontrollers-from-navigation-stack)

Comment: @ codeherk, I TRIED THOSE ANSWERS, DIDNT WORK

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Instead of dropping and all, you can just use:***

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [self]
```

Comment: Self is your current view controller

Comment: @Sheikh Atif  This comes with some problem of navigation. if there is a Back button in your view controller. you won't be able to GO BACK.

Comment: yes, it worked well, and yes the current page is my authentication landing page, no back button. thanks

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger, I printed navigationController?.viewcontrollers after this statement and I saw that the previous vc was still in the stack. Any idea why it would still be present there?

Comment: @SaadRehman Can you please share the navigation structure of your app? check if you are not using multiple navigations in the app

Comment: @JarvisTheAvenger I'm having the same problem that Saad is having when printing the navigationController?.viewcontrollers. Personally I have several storyboards leading up to the page where I need to empty the stack and some of them have navigation controllers of their own... knowing this, is there anyway to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

In the `viewDidLoad` of your view controller set the `viewControllers` property of your navigation controller to the value you want, like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.viewControllers = [self]
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  nc.viewControllers = [AppStoryboard.Main.viewController(viewControllerClass: AuthenticationLandingViewController.self)]

Answer (score 2):

You can also remove it by getting the number of view controllers you have and removing them all except the last

```
if let viewControllerCount = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count {
    self.navigationController?.viewControllers.removeFirst(viewControllerCount - 1)
}
```

If you have 5 view controllers, you would call removeFirst(5-1) so it can remove the first 4 view controllers.