# Dismissing a Game View controller after Performing a Segue to another view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My game looks something like this ----

```
Main View Controller -> Game View Controller -> Game Score View Controller
```

Now, After the game is over, I am performing a segue to the Game Score View Controller. But, the Game View Controller is still not dismissed, and since it detects any touch outside the Game View Controller the app crashes. I would appreciate it if anyone could please let me know how can I dismiss the Game View Controller once I perform a segue to the Game Score View Controller? Thanks a lot for the help!

```
func gameOver() {
    stopGame()
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "2to3segue", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

One way to do it would be to pass a reference of `GameViewController` to `GameScoreViewController`, and then dismiss the gameVC from it.

In `GameViewController`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier  == "2to3segue" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! GameScoreViewController
        destination.gameVC = self
    }
}
```

Then in `GameScoreViewController`:

```
weak var gameVC: GameScoreViewController?
```

and in `ViewDidAppear` you dismiss it:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.gameVC?.dismiss(animated: false)
}
```

---

Assuming that you're using a `NavigationController`, you can use this extension in order to remove the `GameViewController` from the stack after performing your segue:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    func removeViewController(_ controller: UIViewController.Type) {
        if let viewController = viewControllers.first(where: { $0.isKind(of: controller.self) }) {
            viewController.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
}
```

Then once your performed you segue, you can remove the `GameViewController` from `GameScoreViewController` like so:

```
self.navigationController?.removeViewController(GameViewController.self)
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281545/removing-viewcontrollers-from-navigation-stack)

Comment: Actually, I am not using a Navigation Controller in my Game. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer, let me know if it would work in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, in GameScoreViewController gameVC should be
weak var gameVC: GameViewController?  and, even after doing that it is not dismissing the GameView Controller:(

Comment: How was presented GameViewController in the first place?

Comment: It was presented modally from the main view controller!                                           @IBAction func playGame(_ sender: Any) {   
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "1to2segue", sender: self)    
    }

Comment: Ok, what about using `self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false)` in GameScoreViewController?

Comment: I included the following piece of code in my viewDidLoad method but it was still not dismissed:(

Comment: I absolutely have no clue why is It not dismissing the gameView Controller!

Comment: Yes it's weird... is it absolutely necessary for you to dismiss it? Why not making sure that everything is cleared and stopped in `stopGame()` so that you have no crash after, and then you unwind to MainViewController once you're done in the score VC?

Comment: Alright Thanks for your help mate! I have given you an upvote! Cheers:)